# How to get List of all files/directories from a JTree

Tags: java, swing, listview, jtree

I have a JTree which contains file/directory, i want to get a list which contains current list of this JTree.

**How can i do it?**

```
menuItemZip.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean exist=false;
            File[] files = (File[]) tree.getModel().getRoot();
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.getName().equals(selectedFile.getName()+".zip"))
                    exist = true;
                break;
            }
            if(exist ==true)
            new ZipWorkers(selectedFile,WORKING,status).execute();
            btnRefresh.doClick();
        }
    });
```

**Edited as new solution:** just i don't know if it is a good solution?

```
menuItemZip.addActionListener(new AbstractAction() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
           Enumeration enumeration =  ((TreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot()).children();
            String filename = selectedFile.getName()+".zip";
            boolean exist=false;
            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                String file = ((File) enumeration.nextElement()).getName();
                   if(file.equals(filename)){
                       exist=true;
                       break;
                   }
            }
         if(exist ==true)
            new ZipWorkers(selectedFile,WORKING,status).execute();
            btnRefresh.doClick();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This question is confusing. A tree contains a descending hierarchy of items - in this case files. Can you clarify what your list is?

Comment: See [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui).  .. I might have completely misunderstood what you are asking.  Can you clarify?

Comment: My list is a list of Files. I think if you look at the code you can see the `File[]` files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to recursively descend into directories (see `File.isDirectory()` to determine if it is).  The recursiveness can be achieved by writing a function that iterates over an array of files and will call itself with the children of a directory

```
boolean doesExist(File[] files, String searchFileName) {
  boolean exists = false;
  for (File f : files) {
    if (f.getName().equals(searchFileName)) {
      exist = true;
    } else if (f.isDirectory()) {
      exist = doesExist(f.listFiles(), searchFileName);
    }
    if (exist) {
      break; // no need to proceed further
    }
  }
  return exist;
}
```

then call it with

```
doesExist((File[]) tree.getModel().getRoot(), selectedFile.getName()+".zip");
```

Comment: I get `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.ClassCastException:`
I think there is problem with this : `(File[]) tree.getModel().getRoot()`

Comment: @itro - I assumed it worked that way for you already based on the code you posted.  See mKorbel's solution using `TreeNode` instead of `File[]` -- same idea of using the recursion, though

Comment: I did it as below and work but i'm not sure if it is good way?

` Enumeration enumeration =  ((TreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot()).children();
                String filename = selectedFile.getName()+".zip";
                boolean exist=false;
                while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
                    String file = ((File) enumeration.nextElement()).getName();
                       if(file.equals(filename)){
                           exist=true;
                           break;
                       }
                }`

Comment: @itro - you seem to have some type inconsistencies: `enumeration` should contain `TreeNode`s (`TreeNode.children()` returns an enumeration of `TreeNode`s -- see `TreeNode.getChildAt()`), yet you cast the elements to `File`.

Answer (score 3):

easiest of ways is, nice examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/VisitingAlltheNodesinaJTreeComponent.htm) and [here](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.tree/pkg.html)

```
import java.util.Enumeration;   
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.tree.TreeNode;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
    JTree tree = new JTree();
    visitAllNodes(tree);
  }
  public static void visitAllNodes(JTree tree) {
    TreeNode root = (TreeNode) tree.getModel().getRoot();
    visitAllNodes(root);
  }

  public static void visitAllNodes(TreeNode node) {
    System.out.println(node);
    if (node.getChildCount() >= 0) {
      for (Enumeration e = node.children(); e.hasMoreElements();) {
        TreeNode n = (TreeNode) e.nextElement();
        visitAllNodes(n);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for using the model, as well as addressing the actual question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Also consider a variation of [`FileTreeModel`](https://dzone.com/articles/taking-new-swing-tree-table-a-), discussed [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/4447/6692). The advantage is that you need not examine nodes until required.